# Class properties read-only outside assembly or namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object of a class that I want to pass to another assembly via an interface.

Since I'm passing a reference all exposed properties, methods, etc. can be modified from outside the assembly it's been created in.

Is there a way that I can access all exposed elements inside it's assembly (or namespace) and in other assemblies (or namespace) the elements are read-only?

As a workaround it would also be fine to only have an assertion when writing to an element that is supposed to be read-only in the current scope.

Comment: Are you looking for `internal`? `public int MyProperty {get {...} internal set {...}}`;

Comment: For this purpose there is the internal-keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you want the [*`internal`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) access modifier. It limits accessibility to the current assembly.

Imagine we want to build a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   internal int Bio { get; set; }

   private int age;
   public int Age
   {
       get { return age; }
       internal set { age = value; }
   }

   public string Location { get; internal set; }
}
```

- `Name` is [`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) and therefore visible to all assemblies.
- `Bio` is `internal` and therefore visible to the current assembly *only*.
- `Age` has a setter which is *implicitly* `public` because the member is `public`. The setter s *explicitly* `internal`. This means all assemblies can get the value but only the current assembly can set the value.
- `Location` is the same as above but is an automatic property.

You can read more about access modifiers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

(There is one exception to this which is the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute).

Comment: Good answer, I would add that it is possible to place the access modifier specifically on a getter/setter as well (as noted by Dmitry Bychenko in the comments)

Comment: @Saragis Thanks. I updated the answer to include an example of properties.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
  public class Sample {
    private int m_Data;

    // property (and "get") is public - anyone can read the property
    public int Data {
      get { // "get" has "public" modifier as property does
        return m_Data; 
      }
      internal set { // "set" is internal - caller should be in the same assembly 
        m_Data = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

so, within the assembly `Data` is *read/write* property and *readonly* when it's called outside the assembly

Answer (score 1):

You can create Interface with read-only Properties, you can use explicit interface implemention *or* *internal* keyword to restrict access to some of your members from other assembly.

All three approaches are illustrated in this simple example :

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    // has only getter and is read-only
    int MyProperty { get;  }

    string MyMethod();
}

class MyClass : IMyClass
{        
    // setter can be accessed only from current assembly
    public int MyProperty { get; internal set; }

    // this method can by invoked from interface (explicit implementation)
    string IMyClass.MyMethod()
    {
        return "logic for your interface to use outside the assembly";        
    }

    // this method can by invoked from current assembly only
    internal string MyMethod()
    {
        return "logic inside the assembly";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();

        instance.MyProperty = 10;

        // (instance as IMyClass).MyProperty = 20;        property cannot be assigned it's read-only

        Console.WriteLine((instance as IMyClass).MyProperty);

        Console.WriteLine((instance as IMyClass).MyMethod());

        Console.WriteLine(instance.MyMethod());
    }       
}
```

Output :

```
10
logic for your interface to use outside the assembly
logic inside the assembly
```